# Eclipse launch delegate still tells the server status is "starting"

Tags: websphere-liberty, ibm-wdt

I'm running  Eclipse Java EE (Mars) / Websphere Liberty (8.5.5.8) / Websphere Liberty Developer Tools Plugin (8.5.5) on IBM SDK 8.0 64 Bits for Windows.

When launching the server at localhost, the server starts normally and the console writes "server is ready" but the Eclipse launch delegate still tells the server status is "starting". After timeout period, Eclipse says the server was unable to start and kills it.

I know this is a recurring issue : i change connection settings in eclipse to direct, add localhost to etc/host, add -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to eclipse.ini but couldn't resolve it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some known limitations if you have changed the logging settings, see the [Developer Tools known issues and restrictions](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=phil&product=was-nd-mp&topic=r_limitations).

The tools look for this exact message id in the eclipse Console view: CWWKF0011I.  If that message id is not detected the tools think the server did not start.  Do you see that message id in the eclipse Console view?

Comment: Thanks ! The issue was actually related to logging configuration. When i removed traceFileName="stdout" (which is a special value in order to direct trace to stdout as mentioned in documentation), the server start is recognized.

Comment: @florent MARTIN Thanks! The same happened to me. But I had made no changes to the log configuration before. As soon as I commented the log configuration in server.xml, the problem disappeared. I am still trying to figure out what is the problem exactly.

Comment: @mochomecha - Could you please provide what you commented? I have been banging my head since 2 days

Comment: @SK. This is the (already commented out) line of my server.xml:
 
<!--<logging consoleLogLevel="ERROR"/> -->. 

After this, the hanging problem was gone but I never found out the root cause. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am using websphere 9.0 traditional in eclipse 2019-09 having the same issue. Probably because some session is running background.

Resolved by:

1) Go to console->Right click-> terminate/disconnect all. Then agin right click remove all terminated button.

2)If still the problem there remove all the cache in temp files both in application and profiles.